# Angular pipe memoization

Tags: angular

Does angular pipe memoization remember values for parameter sets or just check if the params has changed and then recalculate?

For example, suppose we have a pipe which transforms a number into ”even“ or ”odd”. Then, this number will be changed from 0 to 1, back to 0, then 1, then 0, …

Will angular ”calculate” the string each time, i.e. call the function each time, or will it have the values remembered and therefore just print the known value?

Comment: You can check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pipe-memoization?file=src/app/calculate-age.pipe.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It checks if the params has changed and then recalculate. So for your example, it will trigger the transform function every time. But if for example, it receives "0 0 0 0", it will ”calculate” it only once. In order for it to work the pipe has to be pure ( it's pure by default ). Corresponding docs can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-pure-changes-to-primitives-and-object-references).

Answer (score 1):

It is basically caching the result of a `pipe` transformation based on the `input` parameters. When a `pipe` is used with certain parameters, Angular checks if the input parameters have changed since the last invocation. If the parameters have not changed, Angular reuses the cached result instead of recalculating the transformation. Angular doesn't inherently provide a built-in memoization mechanism for pipes, but you can implement it manually using various techniques.

One common approach is to use a `memoization` cache to store and retrieve previously calculated results based on the input parameters.

Below is an example of using `object` or `Map` in `memoization`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

function memoize(target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  const cache = new Map();

  descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);

    if (cache.has(key)) {
      return cache.get(key);
    }

    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    cache.set(key, result);
    return result;
  };

  return descriptor;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'myMemoizedPipe'
})
export class MyMemoizedPipe implements PipeTransform {

  @memoize
  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
           // Transformation logic here
    return // Return transformed result
  }
}
```